# Django Rest Framework "NoReverseMatch at /" Error When Visiting Homepage

Tags: django, rest

This error only happens when I add an argument to the RetrieveAPIView url like so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('newgame/', newGame, name='newgame'),
    path('gameboard<int:pk>/', GameBoardView.as_view(), name='gameboard'),
    path('findgame/', findGame, name='findgame')
]
```

If I go to the gameboard URL with a valid ID everything works, but if I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` I get this:

```
NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'gameboard' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['api/gameboard(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     3.1.7
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'gameboard' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['api/gameboard(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Exception Location:     /home/calvin/.local/share/virtualenvs/Online-Chess-UxyP2_C1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py, line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  /home/calvin/.local/share/virtualenvs/Online-Chess-UxyP2_C1/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.8.5
Python Path:    

['/home/calvin/Online-Chess/chess',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/calvin/.local/share/virtualenvs/Online-Chess-UxyP2_C1/lib/python3.8/site-packages']

Error during template rendering

In template /home/calvin/Online-Chess/chess/templates/base.html, error at line 0
Reverse for 'gameboard' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['api/gameboard(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

If I take out the `<int:pk>` from the gameboard URL everything works again.

Here is the View:

```
class GameBoardView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = ([IsAuthenticated])
    serializer_class = GameBoardSerializer
    queryset = GameBoard.objects.all()
```

Here are my main URLs, incase that is useful:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name="home"),
    path('<int:game_id>', game, name="game"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('api/', include('api.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls'))
]
```

All of the errors I have found from other people seem to be when they try to access their detail view, but my problem is kind of the opposite. It's like it's trying the `api/gameboard` url before the homepage...

Thank you for any help.

edit: Adding home view code:

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
def home(request):
    return render(request, "home.html")
```

Adding home.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load choosecolor %}
{% block content %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand pl-4" href="{% url 'home' %}">Online Chess</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="findGame">Find Game</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Account
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Game History</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          Your Rating:
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="row pt-5"></div>
<div class="row">
<div class="xl-col-10 l-col-11 m-col-12">
<div class="container" id="board">
  <div class="row mt-2 no-gutters border border-primary">
    {% for col in '01234567' %}
      {% for row in '01234567' %}
        {% if row == '0' %}
          <div class="col">
        {% endif %}
          <div class={{row|choosecolor:col}} id="{{row}},{{col}}"></div>
        {% if row == '7' %}
          </div>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="col-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  const newGameUrl = '{% url 'api:newgame' %}';
  const boardUrl = '{% url 'api:gameboard' %}';
  const findGameUrl = '{% url 'api:findgame' %}';
</script>
<script src={% static "js/game.js" %}></script>
{% endblock content %}
```

...and base.html:

```
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static "style.css" %}>
    
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href={% static "images/favicon.png" %}>
    <title>Chess</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you show the view that is related to the path: path('', home, name="home"). It seems that you have a problem regarding this view

Comment: I'll edit the question above.

Comment: Show `home.html`. And take a look at this pattern `gameboard<int:pk>` feels like it is missing `/` in the middle.

Comment: Tried switching `home.html` for a test page and it worked, so it definitely has something to do with that... I'll add the home.html and base.html that it extends to the original question.

Comment: Ok, you're correct that the issue was in home.html. It was the `{% url api:gameboard %}` that was the problem, because once I added an argument to the url it can't be referenced in that way, I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
path('gameboard<int:pk>/', GameBoardView.as_view(), name='gameboard'),
```

with this another way to put the param:

```
path('gameboard(P<int:pk[0-9]+)>/', GameBoardView.as_view(), name='gameboard'),
```

Comment: `path('gameboard(P<int:pk[0-9]+)>/', GameBoardView.as_view(), name='gameboard'),` gives a syntax error.

Maybe you mean: `url('gameboard(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$'...` which gives me the same error as above.

Comment: @jorge `<int:` stands for the pattern